# The Heisenberg Uncertainty in Bose Einstein condensates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, bose-einstein-condensate

What happens to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, when a system reaches the Bose-Einstein condensed state?

In our statistical mechanics lecture, we derived the following formula for the fraction of ideal gas bosons existing in the condensed state:
$$
  \eta = 1 - \frac{\zeta(\frac{3}{2})v}{\lambda_\beta^3}
$$
with $\zeta: \text{Zeta function}, v: \text{volume per particle}, \lambda_\beta: \text{thermal deBroglie Wavelength}$.

So, if you consider the Heisenberg uncertainty $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar$, and shrink the volume, the momentum uncertainty should grow. But because of the condensation, more and more particles populate the lowest momentum state, so $\Delta p$ should shrink.

I found a paper [Observing properties of an interacting homogeneous Bose-Einstein condesate: Heisenberg-limited momentum spread, interaction energy and free-expansion dynamics; Gotlibovych, et. al.; ArXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7081), where the team produces a completely coherent Bose-Einstein-condensate, so the problem seems to exist in practice. But what happens, if they tried to cool down the system even more, or shrink the volume?

Comment: A real condensate will always be localized in an external potential. Therefore the ground state will have a finite momentum width (which is connected to the system volume). Note, that for the idealized case of a $p = 0$ ground state, there is no way of reducing the volume of the system (because the momentum eigenstates will span the whole space).

Comment: $\Delta p$ is not impulse or uncertainty in impulse, it's the uncertainty in momentum.

Comment: Sorry, that was a language issue, because in German 'momentum' is 'Impuls'.